# Should the meta description of the HTML page be started from "This page is about ..."?

Tags: seo, google-search

Which meta description is better for modern SEO engines like Google?

### Version 1

> This page is about the Tesla Model 3, the electric car designed in the
> Tesla, Inc. The content of this page is including the abstract,
> description, development history and some interesting things about
> Tesla Model 3.

### Version 2

This version has no mentions that is belongs to the web page.

> The Tesla Model 3 is a battery electric mid-size sedan with a fastback
> body style built by Tesla, Inc. since 2017. The class is the Mid-size
> car (D), the body styles is 4-door sedan, the price is from 28,490$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2 is by far the better description of the two. Meta descriptions should be written to:

- Summarize the content in the most human way possible. Write for people, not crawlers.
- Focus on targeted keywords that the content is speaking to. Target 1-3 specific keywords to speak about but making sure to avoid blatantly listing them to avoid stuffing penalties.
- Be approximately 160 characters long.

These descriptions act as your billboard in the search results so keep that in mind as you write it. Always ask yourself the question "Would this make me click the article?".

And, don't get upset that it might not appear how you have it written in your desc. Google always reserves the right to alter and or display whatever they want in the snippet descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. Especially, it was easy to understand because you have answered from the conclusion.